# How to click on a dropdown menu with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to click on the menu item like the picture below, so my test can navigate like a user to the next page.
However every time I'm trying to change page with the code below my test crashes and finish running.

[image: Dropdown Menu]

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
    WebElement userMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/section/header/ul[2]/li[2]"));
    WebElement userMenuOrg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"item_0$Menu\"]/li[3]"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(userMenu).moveToElement(userMenuOrg).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the 2 actions.

```
action.moveToElement(userMenu).build().perform();
action.moveToElement(userMenuOrg).click().build().perform();
```